# Using time to determine what instruction is carried out - android

Tags: java, android, time, timer

Is there a way to use a timestamp or other feature to determine what action is carried out?

e.g. when a button is clicked 'A' is performed unless the button has been clicked within the last second, otherwise perform B

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: There are many ways depending on what exactly you want. In this situation you could probably just disable a `Button` using a timer for `x` amount of seconds. For a real answer, you will need to be more specific

Comment: You'll want to use a time-specific constraint if you're dealing with an advertisement that you don't want a user to skip too quickly. Otherwise if you're waiting for a download to finish or something like that, you'll want to make sure you wait for that actual event finishing before modifying the action of your button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use System.currentTimeMillis(), it returs time in millisecond,
e.g.

```
long last_click = 0;

// this is you interval time in milliseconds
long myTimeMillis = 1000;

// ... ... ...

// inside button click function

long time = System.currentTimeMillis()

if(time-last_click > myTimeMillis){
    do_taskA();
}else{
    do_taskB();
}

last_click = time;
```